# filtering the expression before creating an array with array_agg

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any way to filter the data inside the content of an

> array_agg

in one step, without writing a CTE to filter the content first?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below construct:

```
ARRAY_AGG(IF(condition, NULL, column_value) IGNORE NULLS)
```

Below is simplified example illustrating the approach

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1 val UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 6 
)
SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(IF(val < 4, NULL, val) IGNORE NULLS)
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: thanks Mikhail, I'm wondering, if it's possible to not include NULLs in the array also, thanks!

Comment: that is exactly what `IGNORE NULLS` does